# Auto layout if orientation is not an issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently trying to get the hang of Auto-layout in Xcode, and with it, i have found some problems.

Now, i don't have a 100% grasp on how auto-layout works exactly, so as i learn on it might become easy, but i think it is very hard to be honest. I am usually making games, and of thus, i programmatically add a lot of views to the screen. Now, auto-layout seems to mess everything up when i do this, so i constantly have to make sure that every single auto-layout feature is just right, and there are a bunch!

So, if you do not want to support other orientations, is auto-layout really needed? i mean, if i am making a game for the iPad and using landscape mode only, is there any reason for me to use auto-layout?

Thanks on advance

Comment: No. Autolayout is not mandatory. If you don't want to use it you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Auto layout is not mandatory.
2. But auto layout provides a mechanism for dealing with situations when views change sizes and/or locations:

   - changing orientation, as you pointed out;
   - supporting different screen sizes (e.g. iPhone 3.5" screen vs 4.0" screen);
   - controls whose size changes based upon content (e.g. a `UILabel` whose width expands to fit the `text` or whose `lineCount` is set to zero, meaning that its vertical will grow based the number of lines needed to fit all the `text`); with auto layout you can establish dependencies between controls so that, for example, as one control changes its own size/location, others can move/resize accordingly (e.g. to stay aligned with or make room for the other control); and
   - automatically update `contentSize` for `UIScrollView` objects.

Auto layout requires a little time to gain proficiency, but for dynamic, complex user interfaces, it can save you from having to write code to manually change layouts of views programmatically. But if you don't find yourself doing this sort of code, then you don't necessarily have to use auto layout.

I should acknowledge that there are some tasks that are trivial in a non-autolayout environment (e.g. animation of moving views), doing the same task in auto layout can be frustratingly complicated. But if you have complex interdependencies between views (either between the superview and its subviews or between sibling views), auto layout can be useful.

Comment: Okay i see, so auto-layout is great for certain stuff, and not so great for others, so it is perfectly fine not to use it if you don't have views that needs to align themselves in accordance with other views. Thanks for this answer, really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout simply provides rules for the views how they appear in all orientation.It is upto the user to define how to use it or you may follow the struct and spring model .

The major difference between the two is that there no dimensions involeve in the struct and springs while autolayout says the dimensions and values in whch views should be rearranged

[An excellent beginner tutorial fo autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)